# Solution to $\int\frac{1}{x+xe^{ax+b}}dx$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximation

I need to solve $\int\frac{1}{x+xe^{ax+b}}dx$ as part of a larger optimization problem, where the $a$ and $b$ parameters will be optimized in a subsequent step. Wolfram alpha returns the following Puiseux expansion centered at $x=0$:

$$\frac{\log{x}}{e^b+1} - \frac{ae^bx}{(e^b+1)^2} + O(x^2)$$

My questions

1. Is it possible to shift this expansion to some other value, say $x=c$, with a simple substitution, or would I need to re-calculate the series centered around a different point?
2. Are there better approaches to getting an approximate solution, perhaps sidestepping the series expansion? For example, would Simpson's rule, Gaussian quadrature or some other numerical technique give me a solution in terms of $a$ and $b$ that I can plug into subsequent calculations easier?

I am hoping someone with good intuition regarding numerical integration can point me in the right direction. The integrand seems to me to be a reasonably well behaved function, other than the singularity at $0$, so I feel like I should be able to get an approximation that will not make my downstream optimization task too difficult.

As an aside, I only care about positive values of $x$, namely in the $(0,200]$ interval.

Comment: Are the integration bounds fixed or you need the antiderivative?

Comment: @uranix I am interested in positive values, around the $(0,200]$ interval

Answer (score 1):

It is just a bit more complex. Expanding as series around $x=c\neq0$, the integrand write
$$\frac{1}{c (1+e^{a c+b})}\Bigg[1+\sum_{n=1}^p  \alpha_n (x-c)^n\Bigg]+O\left((x-c)^{p+1}\right)$$ and the very first coefficients are
$$\alpha_1=-\frac{(a c+1) e^{a c+b}+1}{c \left(e^{a c+b}+1\right)}$$
$$\alpha_2=\frac{\left((a c+1) e^{a c+b}+1\right)^2}{c^2\left( e^{a c+b}+1\right)^2}-\frac{a (a
   c+2) e^{a c+b}}{2 c\left( e^{a c+b}+1\right)}$$
The next ones are too long to type but you can get them using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5B%28x+%2B+E%5E%28b+%2B+a*x%29*x%29%5E%28-1%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+c%2C+4%7D%5D)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will accept it as soon as I can get around to digesting it.